# How do I configure IntelliJ/gradle to use dagger 2.0

Tags: java, gradle, dagger-2

I have a gradle project and I want to use dagger 2.0 in it. I don't know how to configure IntelliJ and gradle to generate files and let IntelliJ find them?

My build.gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'
    compile 'commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.10'
    compile 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0:jar-with-dependencies'
    compile 'com.pi4j:pi4j-distribution:1.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

In the build directory of my application the file `DaggerXmlConfigurationComponent` exists, which is a component Dagger creates. But I can't use it in IntelliJ because it can't find the class.

This is not an Android application but an application for the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107182/how-to-configure-dagger-in-intellij?rq=1 ? Maybe it can help.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue, the files are generated and if I run my build from the cmd line it's fine, but intellij thinks it's missing the generated files still.

Answer (score 18):

You'll have to manually enable annotation processing for IntelliJ: in Settings… → Build, Execution, Deployment → Compiler → Annotation Processors, check Enable annotation processing and Obtain processors from project classpath.

Answer (score 8):

I've found a solution.

https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.3"
  }
}

apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"

dependecies {
  apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
}
```

Additionally if you are using Intellij a following configuration is recommended:

When using the Gradle integration in IntelliJ IDEA however, rather than the idea task, you'll have to manually enable annotation processing: in Settings… → Build, Execution, Deployment → Compiler → Annotation Processors, check Enable annotation processing and Obtain processors from project classpath. To mimic the Gradle behavior and generated files behavior, you can configure the production and test sources directories to build/generated/source/apt/main and build/generated/source/apt/test respectively and choose to Store generated sources relative to: Module content root.
I've also had to remove Exclude from whole build directory and mark generated/source/apt/main directory as source.

Comment: It didn't work out for me until I added 'idea' plugin. It works even without enabling Annotation Processors.
`apply plugin:'idea'`

Comment: +1 for the last sentence starting with "I've also had to remove "I've also had to remove Exclude from whole build directory and mark generated/source/apt/main directory as source"

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way, I know of is to use the [apt-idea plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin#intellij-idea)

Just activate the plugin in the `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'net.ltgt.apt-idea' version "0.15"
}
```

and then add the annotation processors to the `annotationProcessor` configuration:

```
final DAGGER_VER = '2.16'
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${DAGGER_VER}"
    annotationProcessor"com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${DAGGER_VER}"
}
```

I've created a very simple test-project on GitHub: [ex.dagger](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.dagger)
(using IntelliJ 2018.1.4, Gradle 4.7)

Answer (score 3):

I too couldn't get any of the plugins to work, so based on Stefan's response I did the following which works, but annoyingly IntelliJ seems to create group modules, which weren't there before.  Be great if anyone has any idea what is causing this I would really like to get this fixed.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

configurations {
    compileDagger
}

def genPath = new File(buildDir,"generated/source/apt/main" )

task createGenPath << {
    if(!genPath.exists()){
        genPath.mkdirs()
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn(createGenPath)

compileJava {
    source += genPath
    classpath += configurations.compileDagger
    options.compilerArgs += ['-s', genPath]
}

idea.module {
    sourceDirs += genPath
}

dependencies {
    compileDagger "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${dagger2Version}"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:${dagger2Version}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finished up with the following solution (and it seems to be the simplest one from all the sent answers):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

def generatedMain = new File(buildDir, "generated/main")

compileJava {
    doFirst {
        generatedMain.mkdirs()
    }
    options.compilerArgs += ['-s', generatedMain]
}
idea.module.sourceDirs += generatedMain

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with the existings plugins, so I added the following to my `build.gradle`:

```
def daggerVersion = "2.4"

// APT >>
def genPath = new File(buildDir,"generated/java/APT" )

task createGenPath << {
    if(!genPath.exists()){
        genPath.mkdirs()
    }
}
compileJava.dependsOn(createGenPath)

compileJava {
     options.compilerArgs << '-s' << genPath
}
// APT <<


dependencies {
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
}

// APT IDEA >>
idea.module {
    sourceDirs += genPath
    // maybe add to generatedSourceDirs
    iml {
        withXml {
            File ideaCompilerXml = project.file('.idea/compiler.xml')
            if (ideaCompilerXml.isFile()) {
                Node parsedProjectXml = (new XmlParser()).parse(ideaCompilerXml)
                updateIdeaCompilerConfiguration(parsedProjectXml)
                ideaCompilerXml.withWriter { writer ->
                    XmlNodePrinter nodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
                    nodePrinter.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
                    nodePrinter.print(parsedProjectXml)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

static void updateIdeaCompilerConfiguration( Node projectConfiguration) { //actually resets APT
    Object compilerConfiguration = projectConfiguration.component.find { it.@name == 'CompilerConfiguration' }
    compilerConfiguration.annotationProcessing.replaceNode{
        annotationProcessing() {
            profile(default: 'true', name: 'Default', enabled: 'true') {
                sourceOutputDir(name: '')
                sourceTestOutputDir(name: '')
                outputRelativeToContentRoot(value: 'true')
                processorPath(useClasspath: 'true')
            }
        }
    }
}
// APT IDEA <<
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was IDEA creating a separate module for the dagger generated files. I had to go to `File -> Project Structure -> Modules` and remove the `projectname_dagger` module (by clicking the red minus), then add the generated source folder to my `projectname_main` module by clicking `Add Content Root` and selecting it.

The for some reason I had to delete Dagger's files and let IDEA regenerate them because I was getting errors about duplicate files in the project.

Now it works, event with Annotation Processors being turned off (I suspect they must mainly be important for Android projects).

Answer (score 0):

Since net.ltgt.apt version `0.11` (Feb 2018) you can just apply the plugin `net.ltgt.apt-idea` to `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "net.ltgt.apt-idea" version "0.18"
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile             "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.17"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17"
}
```